# swift cocoa (OSX) IBAction in one window fails calling function in independent windows NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, ibaction

I feel a little less than Swift asking this one but I have become exhausted going in circles on the Swift / Obj-C function calls. This is OSX (Coacoa/AppKit), not IOS where documentation is much more available. We are dealing with NSViews and controllers, not UIViews and controllers.

The problem is surely something basic I am missing, so apologies for this frustration generated question.

Below is the code in a testing prototype OSX App. It is located in the NSViewController for one of the two NSViewControllers contained in the main SplitView controller. It services testing buttons which I place via storyboard in that view. The action code is a standard "switch based on button.title" approach. The first case "Timer Window" successfully launches the independent window set up in storyboard which contains a storyboard generated view contoller.

The second case "Start Timer" calls a function in "ProgressView" which is the actual custom NSView for that new window. It fails with a "missing argument for parameter #1 in call" even though the actual function (also shown below) takes none.

What I know:

1. The function being called works just fine when it is called from withing the the "ProgressView" class itself - I am simply trying to invoke it from a button in a separate window (storyboard requires the IBAction to be in the controller for the view where the button is located).
2. "ProgressView" does appear to be the object instantiated by Storyboard since changing it to "progressView" changes the error to "unresolved identifier".
3. I cannot find definitive documentation to confirm the naming conventions of storyboard instantiations so the item 2 conclusion is "an assumption".

Here is the controller code:

```
  var graphicsController: NSWindowController?
   @IBAction func launchTimer(sender: NSButton)
   {
      let destOp = sender.title
      switch destOp
  {
  case "Timer Window":
     if !(graphicsController != nil)
     {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        graphicsController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("TimerGraphics") as? NSWindowController
        if graphicsController != nil { graphicsController!.showWindow(sender)            }
     }
  case "Start Timer":
     ProgressView.startTicTimer()
  default: println("Missing Button Press action for: \(destOp)")

      }
   }
```

Here is the function from the custom NSView class ProgressView that is the target finction to be invoked:

```
   func startTicTimer() {
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval (0.08333333333333,     target:self, selector: "updateTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      animateStroke(15.0)
      animatePosition(15.0)
   }
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated, I have tried many things and just keep hitting the wall. That's why I suspect I'm having a huge blind spot here.

Answer (score 0):

DUH! I am know that "ProgressView" is the class, not an instance. It was only being burned out from my frustration with trying so many things (+ cryptic error msg) that ended up with the bad assumption noted above in items 2 & 3. Apple is not going to violate their own rule of starting Cap for class, lower case for instance. I simply have no idea what the instance name is or how to find it.

So that gets me back to the basic issue which put me on this death spiral, how do I know the object name to reference the instance that the builtin storyboard logic used when instantiating ProgressView? I will repost using that question.